# Chrome is only queuing 2 ajax requests at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a click event which adds an item to a user's cart server side and client side asynchronously. This works fine in all browsers until the user clicks more than twice in Chrome before the ajax request completes. In the network console in IE and Firefox, I can see the requests being properly queued, but Chrome only queues two at a time and ignores everything else. Even using a success event doesn't help because it fires even if Chrome ignored it.

```
$(div).on('click',function () {
    $.ajax('script.php')
    .success(function() {
        dosomething();
    });
});
```

If you fire this event 5 times in quick secession, script.php will be called twice while dosomething() will be called 5 times.

Is there a way to get Chrome to handle more than two requests or at least call some function as many times as the actual ajax is loaded?

Comment: I can understand it only sending two concurrently, but it shouldn't be giving you success 5 times if it's only actually sending it twice. I suspect something else entirely is happening, likely a race condition of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code to

```
$(div).on('click',function () {
    $.ajax({url: 'script.php',cache: false})
    .success(function() {
        dosomething();
    });
});
```

Seems to have worked. Feel free to enlighten me on why Chrome would cache an ajax request for 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

According to the API documentation, it should be doing it *asynchronously*. Try setting

```
async: true
```

*Should be **default** but maybe your script is changing that somewhere?*
Maybe you need to check the console for errors???

Comment: Check out the error: prop documentation on the $.ajax link above. You should be able to check for any errors. It should be firing. If not there is an error. Anything that has gone amiss has an error. Its up to you to catch it.